# Is Facebook's Timeline layout usable?

Tags: usability, facebook

I feel that the double-column is confusing, and the lack of a exhaustive time-sorted list of my actions somehow frustrating.

I wonder if this is just a reaction to change and a smart idea or just bad usability?

Related article: http://www.fastcodesign.com/1665414/designers-behind-facebook-timeline-5-lessons-for-creating-a-ui-with-soul

Comment: Per the [FAQ], I'm closing this question because it's nothing more than "a rant disguised as a question."

Comment: I can understand the subjectivity, but a *rant*? Where in "is a double column timeline good or bad usability" can you see a rant?

Comment: Sorry, that was a terrible comment. The rest of that sentence in the FAQ gives an example: “______ sucks, am I right?”, and in terms of substance, your question isn't much more than that at this point. There's probably a good question in there, you just need to elaborate, maybe post a screenshot, and summarize or quote the relevant section of the article. See the [discussion about this type of question on meta](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/630/should-questions-about-popular-products-be-encouraged).

Comment: Ok @PatrickMcElhaney I'll take this into account next time, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I personally cannot stand the new design.

It lacks basic flow, does not follow a conventional reading pattern (I don't skim in such a blocky manner), and is overall confusing.

I have no clue what task it is supposed to encourage me to do, other than stand back and try to take in the overload of information.

I know for a fact that Facebook does extensive user testing, so this wasn't just dreamed up and dropped on us.

Not inviting in the least sense, I will stick to the (barely tolerable) Android app (which has its own host of performance issues).

Losing interested in Facebook for 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Mike about the general clunkiness feeling of the new timeline .For someone who spends a lot of time on Facebook,when I get on ,I am now really confused about where all my information is it takes some time for my eyes to adjust .Also the lack of clear delineation of what sections of where causes the eye to wander around until I find something.

With regards to the timeline ,its an interesting feature,but I would have preferred that Facebook used their original wall layout and incorporated the timeline in that.The new layout reeks of information overload and I can imagine people getting lost very easily